# How can I spread node on 2D domain?

Tags: matlab

Is there anyone who know  any function (or any suggestion) in MATLAB, that I could spread nodes on a 2D domain?

It is necessary for me that spread nodes so that the  nodes density be nearly equal on whole domain.

I am grateful to you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `rand`?

If you need 2D coordinates of `n` points spread uniformly on a 2D domain, with width `w` and height `h` then:

```
xy = bsxfun(@times, rand( 2, n ), [w; h] );
figure; scatter( xy(1,:), xy(2,:), 40, '+' );axis equal;
```

Here's a possible result for `n=500`, `h=3` and `w=1`:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot,but how could I use it for any 2D domain, for example circle? should I change [w;h]?

Comment: for arbitrary rectangular domains you can rotate `xy` using 2D transformation. However, using arbitrary transformations that are beynod rotation, translation, scaling the resulting density might not be uniform anymore.

Comment: For a triangular spread see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021381/matlab-generate-and-plot-a-point-cloud-distributed-within-a-triangle). Note how people addressed the subject of **uniform** spread in their answers there!

Comment: For a circular shape, the easiest method surely is a rejection method: generate `xy = -R + 2*R*rand(n,2);` and reject all points that are outside the circle: `xy(sum(xy.^2,2) > R^2, :) = [];`.