# Generating random point inside irregular polygon

Tags: python, scipy, geopandas

I am trying to implement the algorithm provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481514/how-to-get-a-random-point-on-the-interior-of-an-irregular-polygon) to generate n-randomly located points in a convex polygon using `python`. I have been able to complete steps 1 and 3 successfully, however don't quite understand how to complete step 2. Step 2 involves first:

- finding the fraction of the total area that each triangle takes up, and store that in a list.
- generating a random double number from 0 - 1

Using these two ingredients, the user states the following, and I quote:

> subtract each value in the list until the next subtraction would make
>   it negative

I find the above statement highly ambiguous. I understand that conceptually the numbers in the list represent some kind of likelihood for that item in the list to get picked, but I don't understand how to do the above, what needs to be done, or why it means that the weighting of triangle area is taken into consideration.

Could somebody please elaborate?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I also found [this blog post](https://medium.com/@peterkellyonline/weighted-random-selection-3ff222917eb6) which contains additional information, though I'm not quite convinced yet. Perhaps this has already been implemented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `numpy` already provides this functionality in `numpy.random.choice`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice) provides more information. If the areas are contained in a list and normalized, then the list may serve as the probability distribution for the choice method.

Comment: I didn't see how `numpy.random.choice` relates to the location `inside irregular polygon`.

Comment: if you normalize the areas by total area, then that becomes your probability distribution.

Comment: could you please put a snippet code for the solution? thanks.