# Equidistant sampling points inside triangle (3d)

Tags: matlab, 3d, sampling

I need to generate equidistant sample points inside an arbitrary triangle in 3d. By "equidistant" I mean that the points within the plane containing the triangle form a grid with uniformly spaced coordinates in two perpendicular directions.

**Approach 1**:

There is a [really nice algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778147/sample-random-point-in-triangle) to generate uniformly distributed random sample points in a triangle.
I tried to adapt it to my needs, but I only got the following:

```
tri = [-10, 0, -5; 0, 10, 0; 10, 0, 5];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,100));
t = sqrt(X(:));
s = Y(:);
points = (1 - t) * tri(1, :) + bsxfun(@times, ((1 - s) * tri(2, :) + s * tri(3, :)), t);
scatter3(points(:, 1), points(:, 2), points(:,3), '.')
```

[image: approach 1]

The result is not uniformly gridded.

**Approach 2**:

The more "classical" way is to get a grid in the xy plane and project the sampling points onto the triangle plane. I used barycentric coordinates to decide whether the points are inside the triangle or not.

```
tri = [-10, 0, -5; 0, 10, 0; 10, 0, 5];
coeffPlane = cross(tri(3,:)-tri(1,:), tri(2,:)-tri(1,:));
offset = dot(coeffPlane, tri(3,:));
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-10,10,20));
X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);
Z = (offset-coeffPlane(1)*X-coeffPlane(2)*Y)/coeffPlane(3);
points = [X Y Z];
baryCoord = cartesianToBarycentric(triangulation([1,2,3], tri), ones(size(X)), points);
TFinTri = all(baryCoord>=0 & baryCoord<=1,2);
points(~TFinTri,:) = [];
scatter3(points(:, 1), points(:, 2), points(:,3), '.')
```

[image: approach 2]

Thats almost the result I want, but the grid space varies depending on the angle between plane normal and z axis. The most critical problem is that this algorithm won't work for triangles whose normal vectors are perpendicular to the z axis.

Do you have some ideas to improve my approaches to get an uniformly spaced grid of 3d points inside a triangle? Or is there a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: What I'd do is 1) Find equation of plane of the triangle. 2) Find transform between XY and the plane 3) define points in XY, and transform them (not project them) into the plane. 4) crop out of triangle points.  A rotational transform should do the job.